# Knife Project error in Blender

Tags: modeling

I am tired of this error and unable to Knife Project in Blender. Photo Attached:-

[image]

Comment: "Regression"? Wdym?

Comment: You either need to select 2 objects, or you need to delete the faces (X (Delete) > Only Faces on your cutting object. I guess it's one of these problems

Comment: I've tried all this. I have used knife project before & it worked. But it isn't now.

Comment: So it may be a bug as Marty says

Answer (score 8):

Knife project has changed in 2.93.4.

The *new* method:

- Select the destination object in object mode. Do *not* select the cutter.
- Enter edit mode. (Shortcut: <kbd>Tab</kbd>)
- Select the cutter in the outliner (or by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>–left-clicking the cutter).
- Perform the knife project.

Comment: But _Why_? (rhetorical) That's really inconsistent with Blender's notion of an 'Active' object or selection everywhere else. It seems nuts, to me, until I hear a justification.

Comment: It's not listed in the changelog, so I suspect it really is a bug. If I get time, I'll look at the git repository to see if I can figure it out.

Comment: Ahhh.... Sorry, no trouble intended.

Comment: thanks man works like a charm

Comment: Late comment.. it looks as if the change is to allow multiple sources and targets since multiple object editing became possible. 'Active' no longer works, without multiple 'Active'.