# Removing Part of Plane Inside Intersecting Object

Tags: intersection

My fiancé owns a homemade dog treat business and the process of making the small sized treats is very tedious since the cookie cutter is so small. I'm trying to design a cookie cutter that she can use to help speed up the process, allowing her to cut out more than one at a time.

I have made a 3D representation of the cookie cutter shape:

[image: Single Cookie Cutter]

I then duplicated this object into a grid:

[image]

To be able to add structure to this to be able to 3D print, I am trying to add a plane and then remove the parts of the plane that are inside each individual cookie cutter objects:

[image]

I have tried using the Difference Boolean modifier on the plane itself, and use the Collection of cookie cutter objects as the references of what to remove, but that is not working.

What is the best way for me to accomplish removing the parts of the plane that are inside each cookie cutter? TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boolean is usually heavy calculation so it is better to boolean first than array ... anyway for complex, thin objects it is killing way - topology matters. Like if you Solidified cutter outward (and not inward) you generated overlapping geometry in corners, that can be also reason why boolean operation failed.

---

To make a nice clean topology I would take the *cutter*, add two loop cuts Ctrl+R in a middle, scale them at Z axis into a thickness of a plate ...

[image]

*Extrude* and *Scale* ...

[image]

Add a *Plane* above, go to top view and use *Knife Project* operator ([how to use it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/237704/2214) ... I had to search for this answer, usage is weird.) Enable *Cut through* in the operator properties.

[image]

Select outer edges and search for *Bridge Tool* operator ...

[image]

Now just use *Array* modifier with *Merge* enabled ...

[image]