# Cut a logo into a face

Tags: modeling, 3d-printing

I have a plane and I have a logo that is just an extruded 2D logo. The end result I am trying to achieve is basically a credit card size model with the logo as part of the mesh so I can color it and 3d print it.

I've used 3DS Max quite a bit so my plan was to cut the plane with the logo so it would make the faces, color the logo and card, then just extrude it. I can't figure out how to cut the plane with the logo to create faces I can color and extrude.

Comment: I believe you'll want to use booleans for this. Select the plane for your model, add a boolean modifier, duplicate the text and set the duplicated text object to be the boolean object for the plane.

Comment: Thanks mate, I'll search up how to do booleans and give it a go.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Knife Project error in Blender](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/237412/knife-project-error-in-blender)

Answer (score 1):

To use [Knife Project](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/editing/mesh/knife_project.html):

- first in *Object Mode* select the objects to be cut
- then switch to *Edit Mode* and select the cutting objects in the *Outliner* (Ctrl-LMB)

[image]

... and finally choose *Mesh* ‣ **Knife Project**.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I just had to hit the apply button on the boolean operation. The button was under a drop down at the top right of the modifier.