# Unexpected Boolean modifier error

Tags: python

I am new to Blender 3d,i try to use boolean modifier to cut model,but a un except error happened
there is a circle on the "ExampleR",
why after i use the boolean modifier,the "ExampleR" disappear?
if i use "exact" instead of "fast",it works but it take a long time
[image]
[image]

[image: Boolean Error]

another example works correct
[image]

the error example can be got here https://gofile.io/d/wCphqq

the result i want like that
[image]

the selected verts is where the curve intersects with the model

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html

Comment: If you need a cut it is better use *Bisect* Tool

Comment: @vklidu o thank you for you suggestion, I got a new way to cut. But But what I actually want to do is to use this curve to determine an irregular surface and cut it. Bisect Tool looks like he can only achieve flat cutting. My current plan is to use Boolean modifiers to add curve boundaries to the model, and then use scripts to delete the vertices that need to be deleted

Comment: Probably would be helpful if you can ad mockup screen of desired result and share your blend to check it closer what you are dealing with ...

Comment: @vklidu I upload my file an show my desired result  at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not too match to say ... I think all is described in [my first comment link](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/booleans.html) ...

- **Fast** is simpler math that fails on such topology (like yours) with a small parts, even more in your case where the curve overlaps (you can see in your last image)

[image]

- **Exact** is more complicated math for precise result and takes time co calculate

---

*There is not to much options ... [Knife Project](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/308934/2214) partly worked for me (with cut through enabled), but it generates other cuts in projection trajectory. So not the perfect solution as well.*